# Building up a ggplot one line at a time for a presentation

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have the following graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(extrafont)

charts.data <- read.csv("copper-data-for-tutorial.csv")
p1 <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(y = export, x = year, colour = product),
                           data = charts.data, stat="identity")
p1
```

[image]

I'm looking for a general strategy (or perhaps a library) that "builds up" ggplots one line at a time.  So the output would consist of two images, one with just the red line, and the next with the red and the blue line, to be used as adjacent slides in, say, a powerpoint presentation.

Comment: Check [`gganimate`](https://gganimate.com/articles/gganimate.html)

Comment: http://svmiller.com/blog/2018/02/r-markdown-xaringan-theme/ & https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/xaringan.html

Comment: You could filter or split your data so you can build up a list of plots, each with one color-value added in. Can you post a clearer example?

Comment: I assume [this is the data file used](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/t-redactyl/R-graphing-tutorials/master/copper-data-for-tutorial.csv) (CSV).

Comment: Please post a simple(r), reproducible example and remove packages IMHO irrelevant for the actual problem (ggthemes, extrafont)

Comment: This seems like a lot of work to display two graphs that are not really related; for example, you're not showing change over time. I'd be more inclined to create one chart and use facets: `charts.data %>% ggplot(aes(year, export)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~product)`, or just use your original chart. It's arguably more clear that copper > others in one slide, not two.

Comment: Gina Reynolds used a neat process here to accomplish something similar using xaringan:
https://evamaerey.github.io/ggplot_flipbook/ggplot_flipbook_xaringan.html
https://github.com/EvaMaeRey/ggplot_flipbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is filter for copper only in one, then to use `ylim` in both to keep the transition from one graph to the next smooth.

```
# copper only
df %>%
  filter(product == "copper") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(y = export, x = year, colour = product),
            stat = "identity") +
  ylim(0, 16000)

# both
df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(y = export, x = year, colour = product),
            stat = "identity") +
  ylim(0, 16000)
```

[image: Copper only]
[image: Both]